# puppet learning VM

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I have just installed puppet learning VM as part of my learning Puppet.

My base machine is ubuntu 11.04
VMWare installed is VMWare Player 6.0.2 build-1744117
Puppet Learning VM version is 3.4.3 (Puppet Enterprise 3.2.2)

I was able to execute basic commands in puppet VM.

When I tired to install apache from puppetlabs, it fails with the error "The error we caught said 'getaddrinfo:name or Service not known"..

In the VM Settings, I have chosen bridged network and autodetect for networking.

I also tried to install apache from the locally available forge. But it appears to be a HTML file though it has .tar.zi extension...

Has anyone come accross similar issues... or pls guide me where can I post this issue (havent created a ticket in puppet JIRA yet )

Comment: Does you network require signing in through a webinterface or similar?

Comment: I don't think so. I am able to open the link in browser that VM tries to. But not happening through VM...